# Can't load dataset into ipython. UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: csv, pandas, load, ipython, jupyter

Fairly new to using ipython so I'm still getting confused quite easily. Here is my code so far. After loading I have to display only the first 5 rows of the file.

```
# Import useful packages for data science
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
# Load concerts.csv
path1 = 'C:\\Users\\Cathal\\Documents\\concerts.csv'
concerts = pd.read_csv(path1)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
concerts = pd.read_csv(path1, encoding = 'utf8')
```

if that doesnt work try

```
concerts = pd.read_csv(path1, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```